# Error "The source directory ... does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt" while building AWS IoT SDK

Tags: makefile, cmake, aws-iot

I have a very shallow understanding of C/C++ build systems, so this might very well be an obvious question.

I'm attempting to build the AWS IoT SDK as a static libarary as described here:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-embedded-c-sdk.html

In this case I want to build the SDK as a standalone library to be linked to by an executable implemented in Rust.

When I try to build the SDK with the included makefile:

```
$ make -f Makefile
```

I get the following error:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "path/to/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/external_libs/CppUTest" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.
```

The makefile in question is this one:

https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-C/blob/master/Makefile

And I am attempting to build this on macOS, with this make version:

```
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

I'm a bit perplexed by this error, because my assumption was that CMake should call Make, and not the other way around.  What exactly is going wrong here?

Comment: What if you start `make -f Makefile` from directory which contains external_libs directory? See Makefile `CPPUTEST_DIR = $(IOT_CLIENT_DIR)/external_libs/CppUTest
...
PRE_MAKE_CMDS = cd $(CPPUTEST_DIR) &&`

Comment: This is exactly how I am calling it: from the parent directory of external_libs

Comment: Use `make -C` instead of `-f` and specify the directory containing the `Makefile`.

Comment: I am getting the same error.  Can you provide any incite onto what this error means?

Comment: You have to add CppUTest. See file `external_libs/CppUTest/README.txt`. There is nothing currently. That's why you get message about missing CMakeLists.txt file.